# Constant perturbation in Time dependent perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, perturbation-theory, fermis-golden-rule

I was reading the topic of Time dependent perturbation theory by Nouredine Zettili book. In that for a constant perturbation and after evaluating the probability from initial to final state a factor of delta function exist.

The expression is like, $P_{if}=\frac{2\pi t}{\hbar}|<\psi_f|V|\psi_i>|^2\delta(E_f-E_i)$.

He says that this leads to energy conservation. Further he says, a constant perturbation neither transfers energy nor removes energy from it.

So here are my concerns,

1. While solving the problem, we see a $\frac{sin^2x}{x^2}$ kind of nature, and for energy $E_f=E_i$ and for large time, we get sharp peak. But getting a peak when initial and final energy are same, it doesn't make sense to me, as both the states are same, then what is the decay/transition occurring then.
2. Then what is conservation energy taking place and after all what is happening within the system. Like is there any real or hypothetical situation occurs.
3. If the potential is constant, then why study it here in time dependent problem and not in time independent perturbation problem?

Answer (score 0):

The quantity $E_f-E_i$ includes the photon energy.

For example, the transition $1\rightarrow2$ has
$$
E_2=E_1+\hbar\omega
$$

Hence
$$
E_f-E_i=E_2-(E_1+\hbar\omega)=0
$$

The potential $V(x)$ is the time-independent part of the perturbing hamiltonian.

The complete perturbing hamiltonian $H_1$ is
$$
H_1(x,t)=V(x)\bigl(\exp(i\omega t+i\phi)+\exp(-i\omega t-i\phi)\bigr)
$$

where $\omega$ is photon angular frequency and phase $\phi$ is an arbitrary constant.

Note that $V(x)$ is constant in time but not in space.
If $V$ is a pure constant then $P_{if}=0$
because
$$
\langle\psi_f|V|\psi_i\rangle=V\langle\psi_f|\psi_i\rangle=0,\quad f\ne i
$$